# How can I write pyhton code that prints number of words in a file that do not contain each letter of the alphabet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to write Python 3 code that calculates number of words in a file that do not contain each letter of the alphabet, but the loop seems to be working only on the first letter 'a'. Where is the bug there?

```
fin = open('words.txt')
def avoids (word, string):
    for i in string:
        for l in word:
            if l == i:
                return False
    return True
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for f in alphabet:
    n = 0
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if (avoids (word, f)):
            n += 1
    print (f, n)
```

The 'words.txt' file can be downloaded using the following link:
http://thinkpython2.com/code/words.txt

The output appears as follows:

```
a 57196
b 0
c 0
d 0
e 0
f 0
g 0
h 0
i 0
j 0
k 0
l 0
m 0
n 0
o 0
p 0
q 0
r 0
s 0
t 0
u 0
v 0
w 0
x 0
y 0
z 0
```

Comment: Tip: You can use the `ascii_lowercase` property of the built-in `string` library rather than declaring the whole alphabet.

Comment: There are **two** `return` statements in the `avoids()` function.  Not ideal.  I suggest finding a better approach.  Additionally, remember to close your text file, or better yet, use the `with` idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the first time you run the loop you reach the end of the file, to restart at the beggining add this line:

```
fin.seek(0)
```

inside your alphabet loop, just like when you reset n = 0.

Comment: WOW! works like charm, thank you so much @Mariana Blaz, I have really learned from you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file once you've opened it, and split to get the text as a list of words. Then you can loop over the words and the alphabet:

```
import string
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

words = text.split()
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print(letter, len([w for w in words if letter not in w]))
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with reading the file as the loop works finely with the first cast and returns the number of words that do not contain the letter 'a'

I have also tried the following code and seems to be working:
`fin = open('words.txt')
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if (len(word) > 20):
        print(word)`
It prints words larger in length than 20 characters

Comment: @SimonR - You can use the `ascii_lowercase` property of the built-in `string` library rather than declaring the whole alphabet.

Comment: @S3DEV . Nice! Didn't know about that one. I updated my answer to incorporate it. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonR Your output also does not include the word count in the case 'a'

Comment: @SimonR I just need to know where the error is in my code

Comment: @ScientificMaster Fair enough. My answer worked perfectly for me. Not sure what happened there. Also maybe be aware that your code is an order of magnitude slower than my version : 2.5 seconds vs 0.18 seconds for your dataset, on my machine.